# Why does the W3C Validation Service say this is not valid XHTML?

Tags: html, forms, input, validation

Can someone tell me why the W3C Validation Service says that this code is not valid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>this is the title of the web page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="formscript.php" method="post">
    first name:<input type="text" name="firstname" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update your question and put what error is the validator giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both codes and the validator says that the question code is valid as XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Anyway, the problem here is that you have no `<fieldset>` inside your `<form>` and that the text `<input>` has no `<label>`.

```html
<form action="formscript.php" method="post" name="thisform">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="firstname">first name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />

    <input type="submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And don't forget the `DOCTYPE`.

Comment: The `label` element, though useful, has nothing to do with the validation issue. And `fieldset` is just one of the possible block-level wrappers. If used, it requires a `legend' subelement. There are also other markup errors in your proposed solution (some of which did not exist in the original), as you can see by trying to validate your code.

Answer (score 0):

The markup, as originally posted, makes a valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional document if the XHTML 1.0 Transitional document type declaration is added at the start.

As edited by @adamjansch, with the XHTML 1.0 Strict document type declaration, it is not valid, and presumably it was validated using that document type declaration. Then the first error message is “character data is not allowed here” with some explanations of *possible* causes, including “putting text directly in the body of the document without wrapping it in a container element (such as a `<p>aragraph</p>`)”. This gets close: the problem is that in XHTML 1.0 Strict, a `form` element may have block-level children only.

This means that any text and text-level markup like `input` must be wrapped in one or more block containers, such as `p`, `div`, `fieldset`, or `table`. Of these, `div` is the only neutral one, with no default impact on rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>this is the title of the web page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="formscript.php" method="post">
  <div>
    first name:<input type="text" name="firstname" />

    <input type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```